# Route named parameters but drop index for all URLs?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

By default CakePHP will drop `index` from the URLs for routes, but once you add named parameters it reappears.

How can I use named parameters for all controllers, but if the action is `index` then hide it?

The default setup is.

```
Router::connect('/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*');
```

When I request `/controller/named:1` it routes to an action `named:1()` and throws an error. It's obvious as to why.

Somehow I need to check if the text after the controller is only a named parameter and map to `index`.

Comment: The default here is `/controller/index/named:1` and works just fine. Why do you need to make the action disappear?

Comment: @mark Javascript code needs to add named parameters and doesn't know what the current action is. I like to keep `index` hidden as it reads better. Otherwise I have to force it to always show.

Comment: @mark I also wouldn't know the difference between `/something/that` as `controller` and `action` or if it's `plugin` and `controller`.

Comment: I see. You could echo the action name to JS in your view as a workaround.

Comment: @mark that is true, and I'll do that for now.